# connectivity in automata by words of length n-1

Tags: automata-theory, matrices, linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a complete strongly connected automaton with $n$ states. Does always exist a word $v$ of length at most $n-1$ such that its underlying graph is connected? 
That is for any pair of distinct states $p,q$ exists a positive integer $k$ such that either $p.v^k = q$ or $q.v^k = p$. Additionaly we can assume that there exists a word $w$ such that its underlying graph is connected.

The statement also can be reformulated in terms of linear algebra.

Comment: The automaton is deterministic. Right? 

Comment: >The automaton is deterministic. Right?
right

Comment: There are some other assumptions missing otherwise the answer is obviously "no", see my answer. 

Comment: The assumption is "Additionaly we can assume that there exists a word w such that its underlying graph is connected." and we can also assume that $w$ takes $A$ into one state, but I think it is not necessary.

Comment: Assumption that $|Aw|=1$ implies that the GCD of the lengths of cyclies in $A$ is 1 (see Trakhtman's theorem). Perhaps you should reformulate the question putting the necessary assumptions before the question itself. The question should say something like: If there exists $w$ for which $(A,w)$ is connected, then there exists such a $w$ of length at most $n-1$.  

Comment: I assume you are interested in the Cerny conjecture.  You want to say if there is some word w whose eventual range is a cycle (or perhaps you are happy with a point), then there is a word of length at most $n-1$. Eventual range is the image of the idempotent power of a mapping. You basically want to use the ideas of the one-cluster case more generally. 

Comment: I am for the first time on this site and 
it seems to me that my name is not shown correctly here. 
I didn't want to be anonymous :) it's Misha Berlinkov. So it's nice to see you here Benjamin. If I know correctly my parents are also friends of Mark Sapir. So I nice to see you here too. 

About the problem: actually, I have proved Cerny conjecture for synchronizing automata for which above statement is true. However, the proof appeared yesturday and thus should be checked once more. As soon as it will be done I shall submit it to ArXiv and send you the reference.

Comment: Misha, welcome to MO.  If you don't know a counterexample then nobody does. So in particular I suppose you have solved the Cerny conjecture for 1-cluster automata. 

Comment: Yes, of course, it works for 1-cluster automata and allows to prove quadratic upper bounds for genaralizations of 1-cluster automata.

Comment: Misha, you should be able to edit your profile to put your real name. Does your proof give a new proof of Dubuc's theorem or does it use his techniques?

Comment: I have logged using my google account. I thought my real name will be 
automatically passed to profile.

>>Does your proof give a new proof of Dubuc's theorem or does it use >>his techniques?
Yes it gives a new proof for it but use another technique of Markov chains and linear programming. I hope to submit preliminary variant of the paper today.

Comment: @Misha: Hello! Regards to your parents! I guess Misha Volkov was your adviser? I think he told me that. 

Comment: Hello! Thank you. Yes, he is still my advisor!

Comment: Great I have always been pushing to use Markov chains for this. Please send me your preprint when it is ready. 